# Jenkins Pipeline SCM Checkout: Difference between using 'main' vs '*/main' as a branch name

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control

I've got this custom method, it is used to checkout a specific branch from a Git repository:

```java
        def customCheckout(String branch) {
        def projectUrl = "git@global.gitlab.com:team/team-ci.git"
        def gitTool = isUnix() ? 'git_mac' : 'git_win'
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: branch]],
                gitTool: gitTool, 
                userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'default_ssh', url: projectUrl]]
            ])
        }
```

I've noticed that I can pass either `main` or `*/main` as the branch argument when calling this method. For instance:

```java
customCheckout('main')
```

vs

```java
customCheckout('*/main')
```

What is the difference between these two method calls? When should I use `main` and when should I use `*/main`? How does the behaviour of the `customCheckout` function change based on the type of branch name I pass?

I would appreciate any insights on this.